# SQL query : SELECT

Tags: sql, select

```
CREATE TABLE WRITTEN_BY
( Re_Id             CHAR(15)    NOT NULL,
  Pub_Number            INT     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Re_Id, Pub_Number),
FOREIGN KEY(Re_Id) REFERENCES RESEARCHER(Re_Id),
FOREIGN KEY(Pub_Number) REFERENCES PUBLICATION(Pub_Number));


CREATE TABLE WORKING_ON
( Re_Id             CHAR(15)    NOT NULL,
  Pro_Code          CHAR(15)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Re_Id, Pro_Code, Subpro_Code)
FOREIGN KEY(Re_Id) REFERENCES RESEARCHER(Re_Id));
```

**Re_Id** stands for *ID of a researcher*

**Pub_Number** stands for *ID of a publication*

**Pro_Code** stands for *ID of a project*

**Written_by** table stores information about a Publication's ID and it's author

**Working_on** table stores information about a Project's ID and who is working on it

Now, I have this query :

```
For each project, find the researcher who wrote the most number of publications .
```

This is what i've done so far :

```
SELECT Pro_Code,WORK.Re_Id
FROM WORKING_ON AS WORK , WRITTEN_BY AS WRITE
WHERE WORK.Re_Id = WRITE.Re.Id
```

so I got a table which contains personal ID and  project's ID of a researcher who has at least 1 publication. But what's next ? How to solve this problem?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said which platform you're on but try this. It handles the case where there are ties as well.

```
select g.Pro_Code, g.Re_Id, g.numpublished
from
    (
        SELECT work.Pro_Code, WORK.Re_Id, count(WRITE.pub_number) as numpublished
        FROM WORKING_ON WORK JOIN WRITTEN_BY AS WRITE ON WORK.Re_Id = WRITE.Re_Id
        GROUP BY work.Pro_Code, WORK.Re_Id
    ) g
    inner join
    (
        select Pro_code, max(numpublished) as maxpublished
        from (
            SELECT work.Pro_Code, WORK.Re_Id, count(WRITE.pub_number) numpublished
            FROM WORKING_ON WORK JOIN WRITTEN_BY AS WRITE ON WORK.Re_Id = WRITE.Re_Id
            GROUP BY work.Pro_Code, WORK.Re_Id
        ) g2
        group by Pro_code
    ) m
        on m.Pro_code = g.Pro_Code and m.maxpublished = g.numpublished
```

Some platforms will allow you to write it this way:

```
with g as (
    SELECT work.Pro_Code, WORK.Re_Id, count(WRITE.pub_number) as numpublished
    FROM WORKING_ON WORK JOIN WRITTEN_BY AS WRITE ON WORK.Re_Id = WRITE.Re_Id
    GROUP BY work.Pro_Code, WORK.Re_Id
)
select g.Pro_Code, g.Re_Id, g.numpublished
from g
    inner join
    (
        select Pro_code, max(numpublished) as maxpublished
        from g
        group by Pro_code
    ) m
        on m.Pro_code = g.Pro_Code and m.maxpublished = g.numpublished
```

Comment: Wait, but I think  in g2 , you must group it by WORK.Pro_Code like this :
select Pro_code,max(numpublished) as maxpublished
from (...)
group by WORK.Pro_Code

Comment: You're right that I accidentally left out the grouping clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL, this should work:

```
With cte as (
select a.Re_Id, Pub_Number,Pro_Code, COUNT(distinct Pub_Number) as pubs
from WRITTEN_BY a 
inner join WORKING_ON b
on a.Re_Id = b.Re_Id)

SELECT Re_Id,pubs from cte
HAVING pubs = MAX(pubs)
GROUP BY Re_Id
```

Comment: You're grouping by `pubs` so it will always be true that `pubs = max(pubs)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for something like the following :

```
select
    tm.pro_code as pro_code,
    tm.re_id    as re_id,
    max(total)  as max_pub 
from (
    select *
    from (
        select
            wo.pro_code          as pro_code
            wr.re_id             as re_id,
            count(wr.pub_number) as total
        from
            written_by wr,
            working_on wo
        where
            wr.re_id = wo.re_id
        group by wr.re_id,wo.pro_code
    )
) tm
group by pro_code
```